# How do I run an application (i.e. IntelliJ IDEA) on a mac remotely from a different machine(any OS) using command line only?

Tags: intellij-idea, ssh, remote-access, vnc

I have looked up options such as SSH and VNC, but could not find a clear solution. I would be great if someone could point me to specifically the solution to this task.